# Applying group by in pipeline of aggregate with 2 matching documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to apply group by on a field named material and sum aggregator on raisedGrnQuantity. Both this material and raisedGrnQuantity are in an array poDetails.
I have constructed a aggregation pipeline to give a rough idea what actually I am trying to do :

```
var projectQry = [
                {
                    "$unwind": {
                        path : '$poDetails',
                        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    $match: {
                        "trackNo": campaignId,
                        "vendorNo": vendorNo,
                        "poDetails.material": output[i].materialCode,
                        "status": "Pending"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        "poDetails.raisedGrnQuantity": 1,
                        "poDetails.material": 1
                    }
                }
            ];
```

The output of this aggregation pipeline is :

```
[
  {
    _id: 62de2e7f1ad8470012b9dc75,
    poDetails: { material: '300000114', raisedGrnQuantity: '20' }
  },
  {
    _id: 62de30ea1ad8470012b9dc78,
    poDetails: { material: '300000114', raisedGrnQuantity: '15' }
  }
]
[
  {
    _id: 62de2e7f1ad8470012b9dc75,
    poDetails: { material: '910000029', raisedGrnQuantity: '10' }
  },
  {
    _id: 62de30ea1ad8470012b9dc78,
    poDetails: { material: '910000029', raisedGrnQuantity: '5' }
  }
]
```

If we notice, there are two different arrays in output because I have two different matching documents in DB.

Now, what exactly I want to do is to apply group by on the material and sum aggregation on raisedGrnQuantity so that I will have output like below :

```
  {
    raisedGrnQuantity: '35'
    material: '300000114'
  },
  {
    raisedGrnQuantity: '15'
    material: '910000029'
  }
```

I tried to use below group by in the pipeline but it is not giving the correct output. Instead of summation of raisedGrnQuantity, it is showing 0.

```
$group: {
            _id: "$poDetails.material",
            raisedGrnQuantity: { $sum: "$poDetails.raisedGrnQuantity" }
        }
```

I suspect the issue is because of two matching documents which causes the output to be two different arrays.

Comment: Add some sample docs, links to playground of mongodb if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is because the type of "podDetail.raisedGrnQuantity" is string, so `$sum` is ignoring it.

All you need to do is cast it to be a number by using `$toInt`, like so:

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$poDetails.material",
      raisedGrnQuantity: {
        $sum: {
          "$toInt": "$poDetails.raisedGrnQuantity"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ae_0J2FnSL7)

Comment: Thanks for answering. There is a difference between my output of aggregation pipeline and the output which you took on Mongo Playground. My output consists of two different arrays due to multiple matching documents in DB but in yours, it's only one. Your observation is correct that I missed string conversion to integer but still it's not working.

Comment: can you provide a full stucture then? the structure you provided is not a valid json. so i just assumed it's a mistake

Comment: That structure was output of aggregation pipeline without group. Because of multiple matching documents, it is showing multiple arrays in output

Comment: The output of aggregation is a single array, is there a change your structure is actually `[ {fieldName: [.. results ..] } , { fieldName: [.. results ..] } ]` ?

Comment: I just tried to console.log the output and I am getting the same output as above. Inside a DB, there are multiples documents which are getting matched with the criteria which I mentioned under $match

Comment: maybe create a [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) sample then instead?

Comment: After debugging little more, I found my mistake. Thank you so much for the help and sorry for bothering too much. One last query. I am getting this error - MongoError: invalid operator '$toInt'. Do I need to update my mogoose version??

Comment: Currently, I have "mongoose": "^5.7.6", installed

Comment: It's a mongodb version issue, if your using a version less than 4 then you'll have to do the casting in memory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246730/discussion-between-atul-kumar-and-tom-slabbaert).